# See in AZ DevOps which branches have been merged already and which ones not

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a possibility to see which branches are already merged? When I go to the branches view, I can list all branches but
a) I don't see the pull request for those where the pull request has already been completed and 
b) the "Status" column does not show any information (what is the purpose of this column anyway?)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the which branches have been merged from the **Completed** tab of **Pull Request**s section. Check below screenshot:
[image]

In the **Branches** View, the **Pull Request column** shows the current active pull request(Not completed yet).

The Status column show the current branch's build status of the [azure pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops) associated with this repo (`Report build status`  option needs to be checked in the build pipeline),

[image]

[image]

Hope above helps!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately on my system the Pull Request column is empty no matter on which branch I look. Is there one or multiple criteria for showing/hiding the pull request information. Is the "compare" branch having an effect on that?

Comment: the Pull Request column only shows the pull request that is active currently.  If all PRs are completed, then the column will be empty.  "compare" branch doesnot have an effect on this. You should find the merged branches from the Pull Requests section under Repos as shown in the first screenshot